# Failed assertion: line 67 pos 16: 'map['projectId'] != null': 'projectId' cannot be null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Suddenly my app start showing following error:

```
E/flutter (16810): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/firebase_options.dart': Failed assertion: line 67 pos 16: 'map['projectId'] != null': 'projectId' cannot be null.
E/flutter (16810): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
E/flutter (16810): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter (16810): #2      new FirebaseOptions.fromMap (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/firebase_options.dart:67:16)
E/flutter (16810): #3      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeFirebaseAppFromMap (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:44:23)
E/flutter (16810): #4      ListMixin.forEach (dart:collection/list.dart:86:13)
E/flutter (16810): #5      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:34:10)
E/flutter (16810): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16810): #6      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:75:7)
E/flutter (16810): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16810): #7      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:44:9)
E/flutter (16810): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16810): #8      main (package:athomedoc/main.dart:10:3)
E/flutter (16810): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16810):
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the code this error points to.

Answer (score 0):

according to error you are getting null value of `projectId`, you can print/debug before using it, to make sure you are getting data from source.